Question about the existence of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$.
I'm currently working on the following problem:

Evaluate the following when they exist in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$:
In $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$ we have $2 \times 5 = 4 \times 7 = 1$, and $5 \times 6 = 3$, so that $\frac{1}{2} = 5, \frac{1}{4} = 7$ and $\frac{3}{5} = 6$. However neither $\frac{1}{3}$ nor $\frac{5}{6}$ can exist in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$, for otherwise it would follow quickly that one of the numerators would be a multiple of $3$, a contradiction.

I can't seem to first of all understand why $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{5}{6}$ don't exist in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$ as a result of one the numerators becoming a multiple of $3$, and also why this leads to a contradiction. I was hoping that someone could further elaborate.

I think I see why you didn't find their explanation clear, but perhaps let's put it this way: Can you find $x$ such that $3x = 1$? Or such that $6x = 5$? (In $\mathbb{Z}_9$, that is.)

You cannot deduce in $\mathbb Z_9$ that $5\times6=3$ implies $5=\dfrac12$ (Why?)

@BrianTung: No, I'm not able to find such an $x$.

@Piquito: I'm not exactly sure why.

If $x = \frac{1}{3}$ exists it should satisfy $3x=1$ in $\Bbb Z_9$, equivalently $3x\equiv 1 \pmod 9$, which means $9 \mid 3x-1$ which is absurd because $3x-1$ is obviously not a multiple of $3$, let alone a multiple of $9$.
